# MySql query is not returning correct results with inner join

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I am working on a MySql query that will return a filtered result from a set of results. However, the result is not using the join as expected.

First, here is the query that returns my initial data:

```
select `jobs`.* from `jobs` 
where exists (
    select * from `job_users` 
    where `jobs`.`number` = `job_users`.`job_number` 
    and `user_id` = 77
) 
and `is_active` = 1 
and `is_complete` = 0 
order by `number` desc 
limit 50 
offset 0;
```

This returns a dataset with 14 rows. I now wish to search within this and return a subset of my original data. This is what I have:

```
select `jobs`.* from `jobs` 
inner join `clients` on `jobs`.`client_id` = `clients`.`id` 
inner join `job_comments` on `jobs`.`client_id` = `job_comments`.`id` 
where exists (
    select * from `job_users` 
    where `jobs`.`number` = `job_users`.`job_number` 
    and `user_id` = 77
) 
and `is_active` = 1 
and `is_complete` = 0 
and `clients`.`title` like '%se%' 
or `jobs`.`title` like '%se%' 
or `jobs`.`number` like '%se%'
or `job_comments`.`comment` like '%se%'
order by `number` desc 
limit 50 
offset 0;
```

This returns a dataset derived from the entire jobs table and not the subset of jobs belonging to the user with the id of 77.

using explain on this query i get:

```
id | select_type        | table        | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                      | key                        | key_len | ref                           | rows  | filtered | Extra
1  | PRIMARY            | jobs         | NULL       | index  | jobs_client_id_index                               | PRIMARY                    | 8       | NULL                          | 20799 | 100.00   | Using where; Backward index scan
1  | PRIMARY            | clients      | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                            | PRIMARY                    | 8       | laravel_ja_dec.jobs.client_id | 1     | 100.00   | NULL
1  | PRIMARY            | job_comments | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                            | PRIMARY                    | 8       | laravel_ja_dec.jobs.client_id | 1     | 100.00   | Using where
2  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | job_users    | NULL       | ref    | job_users_job_number_index,job_users_user_id_index | job_users_job_number_index | 8       | laravel_ja_dec.jobs.number    | 1     | 2.78     | Using where
```

I tried adjusting the ordering (placing the inner join later but this failed with an error.

How do I achieve this result so that it is a subset of the first query and not over the entire jobs table?

Thanks

*** EDIT ***
Following suggestions in reponses i tried adding parenthesis around the or conditions and this looks better (result is 11 items)

```
select `jobs`.* from `jobs`
inner join `clients` on `jobs`.`client_id` = `clients`.`id`
inner join `job_comments` on `jobs`.`client_id` = `job_comments`.`id`
where exists (
    select * from `job_users`
    where `jobs`.`number` = `job_users`.`job_number`
    and `user_id` = 77
) and 
`is_active` = 1 and
`is_complete` = 0 and 
(
    `clients`.`title` like '%se%' or
    `jobs`.`title` like '%se%' or 
    `jobs`.`number` like '%se%' or
    `job_comments`.`comment` like '%se%'
)
order by `jobs`.`number` desc;
```

Thanks for the pointers guys!

Comment: Maybe it's a time to read about the operators precedence?

Comment: A quick google search on operator precedence found this page https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html just not sure on the relevance, I have my and's before my or's?

Comment: I have placed parenthesis around the or conditions and this looks better. See edit